# Is there way to delete the most recent row by comparing it using Timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql

RunFile Table:

```
Sample_Id    Created_On
filename.csv 09/25/2017 16:17:33
filename.csv 09/25/2017 16:10:33
```

I need to delete the row  with the most recent timestamp.

This query gives the old record.

```
SELECT  min(RunFile.`Created_On`) FROM RunFile WHERE Sample_Id='filename.csv'
```

I am trying something like below  but its not working as expected:

```
DELETE From RunFile WHERE RunFile.`Created_On` IN (SELECT  min(RunFile.`Created_On`) FROM RunFile WHERE Sample_Id='filename.csv')
```

Can anyone please help me on how to delete the old record based on timestamp.

Answer (score 2):

You can order by and limit in DELETE query:

```
DELETE FROM RunFile WHERE Sample_Id = 'filename.csv' ORDER BY Created_On DESC LIMIT 1
```

I strongly advice to change Created_On column to datetime which has format 'Y-m-d H:i:s' or timestamp. In current string format order by won't work as you expect. 10/25/2016 is bigger than 09/25/2017.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Created_On column is of Timestamp datatype. In that case I shouldnt get any problem for the above scenario you mentioned right?

Answer (score 2):

You could try delete the values for sample_id not in max( Created_On)

```
delete from  RunFile
where ( Sample_Id, Created_On ) not in (

  select * from (

  select  Sample_Id, max(Created_On)
  from RunFile
  group by sample_id ) t

) 
and Sample_Id = 'filename.csv'
```

Comment: How does something like this get upvoted?  First, the subquery doesn't have a `from`.  Second, if it did, it would not work in MySQL.  (I can understand the answer and the "typo" in missing the `from`; it is the upvotes that baffle me.)

Comment: . . The answer is still incorrect, because you cannot refer to the table being modified in a subquery in the delete.